# puppeteer : use an external function with dom interaction

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

With puppeteer chrome test dev tool , I want to set and use an external func

```
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    async function setSelectVal(page, sel, val) {
        page.evaluate((data) => {
            return document.querySelector(data.sel).value = data.val
        }, {sel, val})
    }

 (async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.goto('url',  {waitUntil: 'load'});

  const inputLogin = await page.$('input[name=login]');
  await page.focus('input[name=login]');
  await page.type('login',  {delay: 100});

  const inputPassord = await page.$('input[name=password]');
  await inputPassord.click();
  await page.type('pass', {delay: 100});

  const inputValidate = await page.$('input[name=valid]');
  await inputValidate.click();

  await page.waitForSelector('td.newpageclass');

  await setSelectVal(page, 'select[name=targetname]', 'targetvalue')
 })();
```

but it triggers an error:

> (node:16312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate):
>   Target closed. (node:16312) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
>   promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
>   that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
>   non-zero exit code.

Do you know how I should do?

Comment: Not much of an expert on this, but seems like browser.newPage() is failing, do a try catch and check the exception, even sounds like page is null (i.e. browser.newPage() is either not a promise or returns empty?

Comment: @PiniH thank fr answere , non newage works  I edit page for showing the case with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just scoping issue: 
Your setSelectVal function doesn't have the page variable, make sure to pass it to it.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function setSelectVal(page, sel, val) {
    return await page.evaluate((data) => {
        return document.querySelector(data.sel).value = data.val
    }, {sel, val})
}

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('url',  {waitUntil: 'load'});
  await setSelectVal(page, 'select[name=targetname]', 5)
})();
```

Comment: unfortunatey I had try that before and it triggers another error, I have edited question to display error

Comment: Try awaiting for the setSelectVal

Comment: now error is : (node:16312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Protocol error (Runtime.evaluate): Target closed.
(node:16312) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Also await the page.evaluate, what (I think) happens is because you don't await things are shutting down as it thinks it doesn't have to do anything